# upgrading d3js from v3 to v4 causes zoom problems

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using d3js v3, and I want to upgrade to v4, but upgrading to v4 causes zoom to be `undefined`

here's the code :

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 8]).on("zoom", zoomed);
```

Error as shown in the console :

```
index.html:192 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'zoom' of undefined
```

I used this example as a reference to my implementation :

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708

The code @ Github pages :

http://jmargieh.github.io/NBA-shots-chart-d3js/

Thanks for the help.

Comment: please check the api changes before posting a question,https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#zooming-d3-zoom

Comment: its completely straight forward.

Comment: I know the problem is due version update, but I didn't manage to solve it :), thanks anyway

Comment: Check documentation. `d3.behavior.zoom` changed to `d3.zoom`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, somethings have been renamed thats all.

```js
var margin = {top: -5, right: -5, bottom: -5, left: -5},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 10])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

var drag = d3.drag()
    .subject(function(d) { return d; })
    .on("start", dragstarted)
    .on("drag", dragged)
    .on("end", dragended);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.right + ")")
    .call(zoom);

var rect = svg.append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("pointer-events", "all");

var container = svg.append("g");

container.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
  .selectAll("line")
    .data(d3.range(0, width, 10))
  .enter().append("line")
    .attr("x1", function(d) { return d; })
    .attr("y1", 0)
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d; })
    .attr("y2", height);

container.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
  .selectAll("line")
    .data(d3.range(0, height, 10))
  .enter().append("line")
    .attr("x1", 0)
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d; })
    .attr("x2", width)
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d; });

d3.tsv("dots.tsv", dottype, function(error, dots) {
  dot = container.append("g")
      .attr("class", "dot")
    .selectAll("circle")
      .data(dots)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
      .call(drag);
});

function dottype(d) {
  d.x = +d.x;
  d.y = +d.y;
  return d;
}

function zoomed() {
  container.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}

function dragstarted(d) {
  d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
  d3.select(this).classed("dragging", true);
}

function dragged(d) {
  d3.select(this).attr("cx", d.x = d3.event.x).attr("cy", d.y = d3.event.y);
}

function dragended(d) {
  d3.select(this).classed("dragging", false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For zooming v3 vs v5 (which might be the same changes to goto v4), I posted in another related stackoverflow about this if this is useful to people visiting this issue: [dagre-d3 js Zoom Fit to all contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36667194/dagre-d3-js-zoom-fit-to-all-contents/56434831#56434831)